# Linearity of the derivative operator of polynomials

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, proof-writing, frechet-derivative

Suppose $f(x)=x^i$ as a simple polynomial function of power $i$. As we know from the definition of the derivative operators, such an operator must be linear. How can we prove that the derivative operator of polynomials is actually a linear operator?
 I am specifically interested in using Fréchet derivative formula to give a proof.

Comment: You can actually show that the derivative is linear for every function using the limit definition.

Comment: @Javi but the limit definition of derivative requires the assumption of the linearity of the operator; it can not be used to show linearity.

Comment: It only uses linearity of the limit, which can also prove if you dare.

Comment: @Javi Thanks for your response. Consider Fréchet derivative. If there exists a bounded **linear** operator $D(.): V\rightarrow U$ such that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{||f(x+h)-f(x)-Df(x)h||}{||h||}=0$ holds, then $D(.)$ is the unique derivative of $f(x)$. Do you mean if this operator exists, it is necessarily a linear operator? Or you are suggesting to show the linearity by using the definition? If latter is what you mean, how can I show the linearity principle $D(rf+sg)(x)=rDf(x)+sDg(x)$ by using the limit definition? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: $r$ and $s$ are scalars.

Comment: I am going to show that for a general expression $rx^i+sx^j$ when $r$ and $s$ are scalares, the derviative $\frac{d}{dx}(rx^i+sx^j)$ in Fréchet limit $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{||r(x+h)^i+s(x+h)^j-(rx^i+sx^j)-(\frac{d}{dx}(rx^i+sx^j))h||}{||h||}=0$ can be relpaced by $r\frac{d}{dx}(x^i)+s\frac{d}{dx}(x^j)=irx^{i-1}+jsx^{j-1}$. What do you think about this approach @Javi?

Comment: I think you didn't talk about the Frechet derivative when I read your question, so I assumed it was the usual derivative. Your latter approach feels right.

Comment: Many thanks @Javi . Yes, I'd forgotten to mention Frechet. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
&\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|r(x+h)^i+s(x+h)^j-(rx^i+sx^j)-(irx^{i-1}-jsx^{j-1})h|}{|h|}\\
&=\lim_{h \to 0}\left|r\left(\frac{(x+h)^i-x^i}{h} -ix^{i-1}\right)+s\left(\frac{(x+h)^j-x^j}{h} -jx^{j-1}\right)\right|\\
&=\left|r\lim_{h \to 0}\left(\frac{(x+h)^i-x^i}{h} -ix^{i-1}\right)+s\lim_{h \to 0}\left(\frac{(x+h)^j-x^j}{h} -jx^{j-1}\right)\right|\\
&=0
\end{align}

where I have used continuity of norm and linearity of limit.